Dot Net Core - Work Service com chamadas de API
Possuo um serviço windows que faz comunicação com alguns dispositivos e agora tenho a necessidade de escutar chamadas desses dispositivos, então preciso que o serviço também escute chamadas http. Na minha classe Program.cs faço a configuração:
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
});
builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ListenAnyIP(6000); // HTTP
        options.ListenAnyIP(6001, listenOptions => // HTTPS
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps();
        });
    });
});

var host = builder.Build();

host.Run();

Depois tenho a classe startup.cs:
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "Minha API",
                Version = "v1",
                Description = "Documentação da API",
            });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Minha API v1");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}

E também uma controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class NotificationController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("dao")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Dao([FromBody] ObjectChangesInputDto objectChanges)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            

            return Ok();
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        return BadRequest("Invalid payload");
    }
}

Porém ao executar e testar com Postman eu só obtenho o código 404.
http://localhost:6000/api/notification/dao
Poderiam me ajudar nesta questão?

e pelo swagger funciona?

@RicardoPontual o swagger nem abre
